# Как узнать высоту или ширину изображения javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть картинка

```
<img src="test.jpg" alt="">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready (function() {
        var ishod = $('.ishod img').width();
        alert(ishod);
    });
</script>
```

выдает 0

если прописать

```
    <img width="100" height="80" src="test.jpg" alt="">
```

то получается

Comment: offsetWidth и offsetHeight ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Проблема возникает из-за того что картинка ещё не загрузилась, а Вы пытаетесь получить её размеры. Советую использовать нативную функцию .onLoad

```
 var img = new Image();     
 img.onload = function() {      
   var width = this.width;
   var hight = this.height;
 }     
 img.src = 'http://www.site.ru/img.png';
```

или на jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".ishod img").load(function() {
    var height = $(this).height();
    var width = $(this).width();
});
```

});

Comment: Спасибо !!!!

Answer (score -2):

может, так:

```
var ishod = $('.ishod img').width();
```

или обращайтесь к картинке как к обычному узлу dom

Comment: я имел в виду

    var ishod = $('.ishod img')[0].width();

Answer (score -3):

```
img.naturalHeight

img.naturalWidth
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?